# Differences between Matthews correlation coefficient and F1 score

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy

I have built a binary classifier neural network. I get an high F1-score, but only medium values for MCC. How I have to interpreter these values? Which are the main conceptual differences between these measures?

Comment: What is a Matthews correlation coefficient?

Comment: @Michael https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient